# Cygwin - Connect to Google Cloud Compute

Tags: cygwin, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am on a windows machine and use Cygwin for convenience rather than a full VM. I am trying to connect to a Compute Server using the ssh keys created in Cygwin rather than using Putty.

My Public key created in Cygwin is something like. Is this different from the one created by Putty Gen?

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza.......................qnBn yyyyyy@xxxxxxxx
```

I have added this to the Metadata and I am using the command as below

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xxxxxxx_gmail_com@10x.15x.2xx.6xx
ssh: connect to host 104.155.231.62 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I have disabled IPTables (just in case) to ensure that this goes thru.. However it always fails.. Is there a solution for this?

My tracert Output is as below -

```
tracert 104.155.210.118    
Tracing route to 118.210.155.104.bc.googleusercontent.com [104.155.210.118]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  1     3 ms     5 ms     5 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     4 ms     3 ms     3 ms  nas01-gw.bhandup.hnsbroadband.com [123.108.225.9]
  3     4 ms     3 ms     6 ms  72.14.195.64
  4    14 ms     6 ms    18 ms  72.14.232.202
  5    34 ms    37 ms    41 ms  66.249.94.39
  6    69 ms    69 ms    64 ms  66.249.94.72
  7   112 ms   114 ms   113 ms  209.85.241.81
  8   122 ms   124 ms   124 ms  209.85.250.101
  9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 10   117 ms   117 ms   116 ms  118.210.155.104.bc.googleusercontent.com [104.155.210.118]

Trace complete.
```

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved -

Dont use the Google User id that is setup for the cloud server that are like xxxxxx_gmail_com - e.g.

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ***xxxxxxx_gmail_com***@10x.15x.2xx.6xx
```

Use the Local user systems user id

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ***myid***@10x.15x.2xx.6xx
```

Then run

```
sudo su - xxxxxx_gmail_com
```

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **public** SSH key to the metadata, but specify the path to the **private** key to `ssh` to use in the connection. The client has the private key, the server has the public key.

You will need to change your command line from:

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub [...]
```

to:

```
ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa [...]
```

The easiest way to do both of these steps is to use [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh), part of the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/).

Comment: I used .ssh/id_rsa. But that too gives me the same error. I tried installing gcloud compute.. but its not supported for 64 bit Cygwin

Comment: $date
Wed, Feb 18, 2015  1:22:12 PM

xxxxxx@xxxxxx ~
$ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no xxxxxxx_gmail_com@10x.15x.21x.11x
Warning: Permanently added '10x.15x.21x.11x' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: Also just to add.. I am trying this with the Public IP address assigned to the server and not the Private one thats setup for within the Google Cloud Environment